# Does Mongodb further compresses compressed data while replication?

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set of 3 Mongo instances(768 GB machines) which holds 270GB Mongo data. This data is already in compressed form. Now i added a 1024GB machine to this replica set. Once the replication completed the used space in this machine was only 163 GB (as compared to 270GB in initial replica set).
So does Mongo DB further compresses compressed data while replication?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB secondaries contain the same data as the primary.

This is because a replica set's main function is high availability, and each secondary should be ready to take over as primary should the current primary went down for whatever reason. So for all intent and purposes, a primary and a secondary is interchangeable.

Why you're seeing a smaller space usage in a new secondary is because over time, data files in the primary could be fragmented due to frequent insert/delete/update operations.

Since doing an initial sync on a new secondary is not a bit-by-bit copy, these empty spaces that exist in the primary does not exist in the new secondary, so it's a more accurate reflection of the actual space your data occupies.

Additionally, WiredTiger does not release space back to the OS (unless under very specific circumstances) with the assumption that you might eventually reuse that space again in the future. It does not release space because allocating that space from the OS is a relatively expensive process that you don't want to do all the time. If it does, then WiredTiger would need to do a lot of release/reclaim operations all the time with no benefit other than making your disk seem emptier.

To determine how much space is currently empty and can be reused by WiredTiger you can run:

```
db.collection.stats().wiredTiger['block-manager']['file bytes available for reuse']
```

See [How do I reclaim disk space in WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-reclaim-disk-space-in-wiredtiger) for more explanations and options should you really want to reclaim those unused spaces.

Note that this is assuming you're using a modern MongoDB version that uses the WiredTiger storage engine. The discontinued MMAPv1 storage engine is much less efficient regarding space usage, but in general, their space usage concept is the same.